# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: is not a subclass of NSManagedObject.'

Tags: core-data, ios8

In my APP I have a really simple model with just two classes. One of those is CDAttribute.
[image: CDAttribute]

This APP is in the store and was working. Now I tested it the fist time with xCode 6 today and put a new version of it on my iPad. Now I get this error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '"CDAttribute" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18342e084 0x193e800e4 0x1830f5350 0x183113f94 0x10004450c 0x100043410 0x1833d4434 0x1833137e0 0x18420b6c0 0x10003f758 0x187e3f104 0x187e432dc 0x187e47624 0x187e46b00 0x187e46a58 0x187e3a38c 0x18b605640 0x1833e6360 0x1833e5468 0x1833e3a8c 0x183311664 0x18c41f5a4 0x187c16984 0x10004d0a0 0x1944eea08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

calling this fuction

```
CDAttribute *attr = (CDAttribute *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CDAttribute" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Which I can't understand because I didn't touch the model nor the code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `CDAttribute` is reserved in iOS8. I changed the Classname (not the table name in the model, because then I'd probably loose all my entries when I update to this version) to `SIAttribute` and it worked.

It was the solution, however I'd be intrested if its really reserved and where it is documented.